# Access element in nested list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

Let's say I have a list like this.

```
internet = ["doge", "Putin", [0, 1, 0, "some string."]]
```

Normally, if I wanted to access elements `"doge"` and `"Putin"`, I would just do `internet[0]` or `internet[1]`. Unfortunately, I can't access elements `0`, `1`, `0`, and `"some string."`. I tried doing this, `internet[2[0]]` but I get this error.

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

How can access an element inside of a nested list? If that's what this is called. Thanks!

Comment: You're getting the error because, as people have said, you don't nest the brackets.  When you do that, python is interpreting "2[0]" as "get the zero element of the literal integer 2," which doesn't make sense and so it gives you that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not nest the brackets `[...]` to do this.  Instead, you place them next to each other:

```
>>> internet = ["doge", "Putin", [0, 1, 0, "some string."]]
>>> internet[2][0]  # Get item 0 of item 2 in internet
0
>>> internet[2][1]  # Get item 1 of item 2 in internet
1
>>> internet[2][2]  # Get item 2 of item 2 in internet
0
>>> internet[2][3]  # Get item 3 of item 2 in internet
'some string.'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
internet[2][0]
```

instead...

Answer (score 1):

You need to end each slice before starting another:

```
>>> [1, [1, 2]][1[1]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>> [1, [1, 2]][1][1]
2
>>>
```

Basically, you want to get the inner list first, and then the item in that list:

```
>>> internet = ["doge", "Putin", [0, 1, 0, "some string."]]
>>> internet[2]
[0, 1, 0, 'some string.']
>>> internet[2][1]
1
>>> internet[2][3]
'some string.'
>>>
```